# Dismissing multiple modal views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, modal-dialog

My application presents a modal view (A) from the main view that lets the user make a selection. When they make that selection it opens a second modal view (B) on top of the first one (A).

When I'm done with the second modal view (B), and want to dismiss it, I would like to dismiss the first one (A) and the second one (B) at the same time as I no longer need the user to return to that one (A) either.

The only thing I came up with is:

```
[self.parentViewController.parentViewController.parentViewController. dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

It works, but it just doesn't look correct. Is this OK to do or is there a more accepted way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think that your way is wrong. It is what [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:) recommends:

If you present several modal view controllers in succession, and thus build a stack of modal view controllers, calling this method on a view controller lower in the stack dismisses its immediate child view controller and all view controllers above that child on the stack. When this happens, only the top-most view is dismissed in an animated fashion; any intermediate view controllers are simply removed from the stack. The top-most view is dismissed using its modal transition style, which may differ from the styles used by other view controllers lower in the stack.

Comment: OK, thank you. It just looked strange to string so many parentViewController statements together to make it work.

Answer (score 0):

```
(UIApplication.sharedApplication().delegate! as! AppDelegate).navigationController?.viewControllers.first?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```